# Xcode no continua la actualización

Tags: xcode

**Resumen:**

Tenía las actualizaciones automáticas en el App Store, se ha dado la actualización del XCode y se ha roto, se queda "Instalando" y de ahí no pasa nada. Intenté cancelar la actualización, reiniciar la MacBook y nada.

**Fotos:**

No son de mi equipo y ejemplifican perfectamente el escenario que tengo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De aquí no avanza, se quedó estático.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Intenté:**

1. Cancelar la actualización, no funcionó.
2. Reiniciar el ordenador, no funcionó.
3. Desinstalar y volver a instalar XCode, tampoco funcionó.

**Análisis:**

1. Abrí la Aplicación Console, no la Terminal.
2. En la barra de búsqueda, revisé por la "App Store".
3. Presioné el botón Start.

En las líneas de los Log, decía cómo iba el proceso de instalación, algo como:
"... Completed: 933 of 1000", Luego de un buen rato, seguí viendo lo mismo "... Completed: 933 to 1000", y de ahí no avanzó más. Considerando que lo dejé cerca de una media hora y nada.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posible motivo del problema:**

- No tenía la última actualización del sistema.

**Solución:**

1. Actualización del sistema operativo, en este caso, hacia MacOS Monterey 12.4.
2. Desinstalación del XCode.
3. Ir a
   https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode, descargar el XCode e instalarlo manualmente.

**Consideraciones:**

1. Tener más de 30-35GB libres en el disco porque sino, no te va a permitir extraer el ejecutable del XCode.
2. Instalar nuevamente las herramientas adicionales.

**Sugerencia:**

- Desactivar las actualizaciones automáticas del App Store y activar las actualizaciones automáticas del sistema operativo.